# How do i use “wait until” element before certain page is displayed? (using python 3.7)

Tags: python-3.x, automated-tests, appium

First of all, i am a newbie in testing app using appium (python 3.7). Here, i am testing an app where i have to wait right after login process is completed. I have done this using implicit wait. But now, to make the testing process more dynamic i want to wait until the next page is displayed.

**Note:** I have seen and tried several issues of this forum but could not help myself.

Here's the code:

```
from appium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

    desired_cap = {
        "platformName": "Android",
        "deviceName": "QDG9X18426W11577",
        "newCommandTimeout": "240",
        "app": "C:\\Users\\tahmina\\Downloads\\test-v3.10.apk",
        "appPackage": "com.cloudapper.android",
        "appActivity": "com.cloudapper.android.SplashActivity"
    }

#Making connection with Appium server

driver = webdriver.Remote("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub", desired_cap)

#Here i have used implicit wait to load the login page

driver.implicitly_wait(20)

#Login to the app

        search_element = driver.find_element_by_id('Username').send_keys('test@yandex.com')

        search_element = driver.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys('1155qQQ')

        search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button').click()

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

#Waiting until the next process comes up
if webdriver.wait.until(driver.find_element_by_id('com.cloudapper.android:id/item_bg').is_displayed()):
    print('Run the next process')
elif webdriver.wait.until(not driver.find_element_by_id('com.cloudapper.android:id/item_bg')):
    print('Something went wrong!')

#Searching employee by using ID
search_element = driver.find_element_by_id('com.cloudapper.android:id/edtSearch').send_keys('1018')
driver.execute_script('mobile:performEditorAction', {'action': 'search'})
```

Guide me if anyone of you have any solution about it.

Comment: Please post your code here instead of a link of an image since most people would not bother to open an image.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Actually this is my first post here. So, i am not aware of all the commands

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Python, you can use `WebDriverWait`  and `ExpectedConditions` to solve your problem.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#Login to the app

search_element = driver.find_element_by_id('Username').send_keys('test@yandex.com')

search_element = driver.find_element_by_id('Password').send_keys('1155qQQ')

search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button').click()

# Waiting until the next process comes up
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.cloudapper.android:id/item_bg")))
```

If you want to implement the `WebDriverWait` in a `try` / `except` block, you can handle the case where your desired element does not appear on the page:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException


# Waiting until the next process comes up
try:
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.cloudapper.android:id/item_bg")))
except TimeoutException as ex:
    # handle the exception here
    print("Exception has been thrown. " + str(ex))
```

Because you are using the explicit `wait.until` keyword, you should not set driver Implicit wait. It is bad practice to set both implicit and explicit wait in your automation tests, and can yield unexpected wait times.

On another note -- I noticed you are using explicit XPath notation in some of your selectors. XPath is a great method for selecting elements, but using explicit selectors as such makes your code very brittle. I recommend using relative selectors instead. You can replace this:

```
search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
            '/hierarchy/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout/android.widget.LinearLayout/android.widget.FrameLayout[2]/android.webkit.WebView/android.webkit.WebView/android.view.View/android.view.View[2]/android.widget.Button').click()
```

with this:

```
search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.Button').click()
```

You may have to query on additional attributes such as text --

```
search_element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//android.widget.Button[@text='Log in']').click()
```

Overall, this method is much more efficient.

Comment: Thanks it works for me when using explicit wait in login process. But i also do need to know how to use the conditional statement if element is not found within the maximum time. Could you please assist me on that?

Comment: The first approach you could take is to increase the wait time -- instead of `WebDriverWait(driver, 10)`, you can instead try `WebDriverWait(driver, 30)`. You also might want to implement this in a try / except block -- I'll update my answer with an example.

Comment: I have done this using try/except block. However please post your answer with an example.

Comment: I did update a few days ago — check the 2nd code sample in my answer.

Comment: got it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
import time
time.sleep(0.5)
```

Comment: The poster asked how to use "wait until" function, not time.sleep

Answer (score 0):

This is for anyone who face the same problem:

1. Import **WebDriverWait** and **ExpectedConditions**
2. Use this as explicit wait in your code
   `WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "com.cloudapper.android:id/item_bg")))`